# Gradle tasks not shown in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I've a Gradle project structure and I'm using eclipse. I've installed Gradle plugin for Eclipse.

However tasks aren't shown in *Gradle Tasks* panel, so I'm not able to launch these ones.

```
project/
   build.gradle
   settings.gradle
   .project
   .classpath
```

I'm able to perform any task using command line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you are using Buildship.

The *Gragle Tasks* view only shows tasks having properties `group` and `description`

```
task myTask {
    group = 'my group'
    description = 'my description'
}
```

After changing your `build.gradle` you must 1.) gradle-refresh the project and 2.) refresh the TasksView

Comment: Thanks @Franck. Nevertheless, I've just added the tsak above and after having refreshed project, the tasks keep without appearing...

Comment: Annoying that some idiot has down-voted this without having the courtesy to leave a comment.  There is something which I can't explain, however: in my Eclipse setup in Windows10 tasks without "group" or "description" **are** nevertheless shown under a catch-all category "other"... but in Linux (Mint Cinnamon 18.1) they aren't.  Eclipse Oxygen in both cases.

Comment: may want to add that, per https://discuss.gradle.org/t/custom-tasks-are-not-being-included-in-the-gradle-tasks-view/12760, Buildship by default shows "public" tasks. You can do your current solution or you can change your settings in BuildShip to show all tasks. Both work.

Comment: I was struggling to work out how to refresh the task view (no refresh button or right click option)...  Turns out you can press F5 with focus on the window.

Comment: What do you mean under "gradle-refresh the project"?

Answer (score 4):

For Eclipse 2020-03 and Eclipse Buildship 3.1.3 you can adjust the filter of your Gradle Tasks view to "Show All Tasks". Then you see your tasks which do not have a group set in the "other" section.

The task "compileJava" has no group set and is showed in the other section only if the filter "Show All Tasks" is set:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was missing that!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have added an existing gradle project via import, which may be causing the issue. To resolve it, you can edit the `.project` file and restart Eclipse.
You can check for differences by comparing the `.profile` file from this project with that of a new (empty) gradle project.

Comment: This worked in my case. Due to an internal eclipse configuration, the project's gradle tasks didn't show up anymore. After compare `.classpath` and `.project` files from the root project, I found the problem: a line added with a reference to another project. I removed this line and then the view with the tasks started to work again

Answer (score 2):

In case the other approaches didn't work, try this:

Right-click on the Eclipse project, choose **Configure -> Add Gradle Nature**.