# Eclipse not showing generateProto task under a gradle project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am working on a GRPC based project and am using gradle to fetch all the dependencies and to generate java files from my proto file.

Here is my `build.gradle` file,

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use mavenCentral for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    // ASSUMES GRADLE 2.12 OR HIGHER. Use plugin version 0.7.5 with earlier
    // gradle versions
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
  }
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //grpc
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.13.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.13.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.13.1'
}

protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1"
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.13.1'
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
      grpc {}
    }
  }
}
```

After Refreshing gradle project, I cannot see generateProto under gradle tasks in eclipse. I have selected Gradle project under eclipse to create my project.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason they were not showing up can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669880/gradle-tasks-not-shown-in-eclipse).

Basically the `generate{*}Prooto` tasks do not have a group name, so the eclipse Gradle Tasks view does not show them. You can add a group name to them and then they will show up.

```
protobuf {
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each {
      it.group = 'my gen proto group'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have simply ceated Gradle project and *.proto file in main/proto/simple.proto after building project I can see generated code in build/* folder but When I'm trying to access that from my main class then that proto message class not found by eclipse. Any idea please help.

Comment: @Az.MaYo I'm on the same boat... how can we get Eclipse to consider the generated Java classes as resources

Comment: I moved from eclipse to intellij Idea. Same code working fine.